# Jplayer 2.2.0: can't get current song info using javascript

Tags: jquery, jplayer, playlist

I'm not a js coder so probably this is isn't working just because of my ignorance:
As found in a very recent post inside the jplayer user group, you can get current song infos listening to jplayer play event, this way:

```
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function(event) { 
    updateCurrentTrackInfo(myPlaylist.playlist[myPlaylist.current]);   // send out the media info object for the current track in the playlist
});

// custom function to update the external current track div
function updateCurrentTrackInfo(obj) {
            document.getElementById('currentTrackInfo').innerHTML = '<em>Now Playing&#8230;</em><span>'+obj.title+'</span> by <span>'+obj.artist+'</span>';
}
```

I inserted this code inside a `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` right after jplayer javascript.
Then in the body of the page i made a `<div id="currentTrackInfo"></div>` tag.

Fact is this code isn't working for me, the div remains blank as it is.
Maybe my mistake is that i have to call the function in some way?

Answer (score 4):

here check this

```
jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind(jQuery.jPlayer.event.play, function (event)
    {   

        var current         = myPlaylist.current,
        playlist        = myPlaylist.playlist;
        jQuery.each(playlist, function (index, obj){
            if (index == current){
                    alert(obj.title);

            } // if condition end
        });
    });
```

Comment: What if I want to take the song duration? How would I do that in the same code?! Because now I have only the title and the url.

Answer (score 0):

please check it

```
function add_song(){
    var current = myPlaylist.current,
        playlist = myPlaylist.playlist;
    jQuery.each(playlist, function (index, obj) {
       if (index == current) {
          alert(obj.title);
        } // if condition end
    });
 }
```

Comment: What if I want to take the song duration? How would I do that in the same code?! Because now I have only the title and the url.